# Fractional Exponentiation in Forth

Tags: exponentiation, forth, gforth

I'm trying to write a function that fits a value to a model.

I have a measurement from a pressure sensor and using a calibrated model I have to convert the value into the final pressure management. Doing so involves raising the measurement to a fractional power, in this case x^2.032.

I'm writing this in [Mecrisp Stellaris](https://mecrisp-stellaris-folkdoc.sourceforge.io/), a dialect of Forth.

I'm a bit stuck. I understand 2.032 = 254/125, but is there a cleaner way to write things than to simply take a huge power and a huge root?

Comment: If `a ^ (m / n) == nth_root(a) ^ m` then this will help: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Nth_root#Forth

Comment: There is a [fixed point library](https://mecrisp-stellaris-folkdoc.sourceforge.io/_downloads/fixpt-math-lib.fs) for Mecrisp Stellaris.  Then take the log of x divide by 2.032 and anti log,  `123.4 log2 2.032 f/ pow2`.  I can't test this but it should work.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you both for pointing me to these examples, was unaware of them.

Answer (score 0):

If your language (or calculator) has square-root, then ypu can use that to compute any power. Of course if the language has a power function, it would be better (simpler, faster, more accurate) to use that.

For example to compute

```
pow( x, 2.032)
```

we first expand 2.032 as a binary fraction (for example by looking at it in floating point in hex) as

```
1.032 = 2 + 1/pow(2,5) + 1/pow(2,11) + 1/pow(2,12)
```

Thus

```
pow( x, 2.032) = pow(x,2) * pow( x, 1/pow(2,5)) * ...
```

We can compute

```
pow( x, 1/pow(2,5))
```

by starting with x and taking 5 square roots in succession.
The general method is to loop over the binary expansion of 2.032, taking square roots, and accumulating into the answer when the binary digit is 1